# Spinner radial color bar

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework, spinner

I would like to create effect like this video: http://youtube.com/watch?v=bEVjLfq9lvk

I want to create spinner color with text in center and when color bar are full completed (100%) adding some event.
I think it's more simple use a plugin but I don't anyone and it should works with Ionic. How can I create this module for my app?

Comment: Google for css loading spinner, there are plenty of examples to find. For your specific case with multiple colors (e.q. more than 4, else you can use a div, make it round and use a different color for each border) it might be a bit tricky but should be possible.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a technique or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: @user2415266 how many borders can have a HTML element? How do you animate only one border to degree? :)

Comment: Davide, use gradient radial backgrounds from center. http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ Spin it using ease back in out and CSS3 Animation keyframes. (That's for the intro :) ) For the progress 0-100% (0-360deg) use Google (SO search). There's tons of examples. **Search for radial progress bar.**

Comment: Four borders: https://jsfiddle.net/j79psgme/ But what @RokoC.Buljan said with gradients could work.

Comment: For the first big radial I use an image background and rotate it, but I need some plugin for construct the radial color loading in play mode...

Answer (score 0):

Okay so since you wanted to have a time bar, I made something myself some time ago. Be aware that this solution isn't really the best, since there are rounding errors which makes the bar become slightly too long or too short instead of hitting exact 100% depending on its width. I'm sure there are better solutions, but this is what I got right now:

https://jsfiddle.net/a6wogez6/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="timebg">
</div>
<div id="time">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#timebg{
    height: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #cc0000;
}

#time{
    margin-top: -20px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 0px;
    background: #00cc00;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var timerrunning;
var width;
var currentwidth;
var intervaltime;

function init() {    
    timerrunning = false;
    width = document.getElementById("timebg").offsetWidth;
    currentwidth = 0;
    // interval steps to increase the timing bar by 3px
    // 5 Seconds/(width of the bar) * 3 for 3px per step
    intervaltime = Math.floor(5000/Math.floor(width))*3;
}


function gameStart(){
    // your game starts, you start the timer
    startTimer();

    // timer times out after 5 seconds, the bar will be at 100%
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        stopTimer();
        // do something here like gameOver()
      }, 5000);
}

// function which starts the timer
function startTimer(){
    timerrunning = true;
    timer = setInterval(function(){loop()}, intervaltime);
}

// function which stops the timer and your timeout = level completed before time ran out
function stopTimer(){
    timerrunning = false;
    clearInterval(timer);
}

// the function which increases the width of the timing bar
function loop(){
    currentwidth = currentwidth + 3;
    css( '#time', 'width', currentwidth + 'px');
}

// some css selecting function I found somewhere...
function css(selector, property, value) {
    for (var i=0; i<document.styleSheets.length;i++) {//Loop through all styles
        //Try add rule
        try { document.styleSheets[i].insertRule(selector+ ' {'+property+':'+value+'}', document.styleSheets[i].cssRules.length);
        } catch(err) {try { document.styleSheets[i].addRule(selector, property+':'+value);} catch(err) {}}//IE
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't need this pieces, I need when the game is started, so the one color bar and its loading (when take 100% game is loses so it maybe fire an event and I need to catch it with javascript, I think there is some plugin for this but I don't know anyone)..

Comment: Oh...overread that sorry. Well in that case you should take a variable in Javascript where you count the time and just update the bar element accordingly. I'll edit in some code shortly, done something like that before.

Comment: Thanks anyway :D If have some solution let me know :P

Comment: Updated the answer with what I used for a little game I made myself some time ago. The solution isn't ideal and there might be better ones.